# How to remove total row and group header from excel sheet using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am new to SSIS. I have a excel file which contains grouped data, grouped by supplier as follows

```
Group header line
Detail lines1
Detail lines2
Detail lines3
Group footer with totals
```

Is there any method to remove these Group header and Group footer using SSIS?

Answer (score 1):

You can select a range from Excel:

EG

If you have Sheet1:

```
head    
Name    Amt
John    1
Bob     2
Fred    3
Foot    


select * from [Sheet1$A2:B5]
```

This will give the detail & skip the header.